# Stop createDom escaping test

Tags: javascript

I am using the following command to render text in a stackTrace element

```
messagesDiv.appendChild(this.createDom('div', {className: 'stackTrace'}, result.trace.stack));
```

However when it renders "result.trace.stack" it wrapping the content in double quotes which i believe is therefore not rendering the HTML tags contained in the variable `result.trace.stack`.

Is there a way of rending the HTML tags in the string so that tags such as `<b>text</b>` actually take affect?

**UPDATE**

Ok i think ive figured out why, it is using `createTextNode` in the creation of the node:

```
if (typeof child === 'string') {
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child));
} else {
  if (child) {
    el.appendChild(child);
  }
}
```

Comment: `createDom` is not a spec function, which framework/library are you using, because that's where you'll find the problem. As for getting < and > to show up in the HTML, replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively (or let the framework/library do that for you. Most of them have two functions, one for setting HTML content, and one for setting text content).

Comment: Show us the `createDom` method! If the third parameter will go into a text node, then it won't parse HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to let HTML tags take effect?

You can change the `createDom` function not to construct a text node, but use the `innerHTML` property:

```
if (typeof child === 'string') {
  el.innerHTML = child;
} …
```

If you needed plain text then, you would need to explicitly construct the text node in the call, like

```
this.createDom('div', {className: 'stackTrace'}, document.createTextNode(result.plainString))
```

So if you want `createDom` to be backwards compatible, you should make it an extra flag whether `innerHTML` should be used.

If you cannot change `createDom`, then you have two choices: Either pass a `documentFragment` with the respective contents, which you would need to construct in a complicated way, as `child`; or you pass nothing an set `innerHTML` explicitly on the resulting element:

```
var el = this.createDom('div', {className: 'stackTrace'});
el.innerHTML = result.trace.stack;
messagesDiv.appendChild(el);
```